# Creating Table From Lists using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, table, list

I want to create table-format feature collection from a couple of lists. These lists only have 4 elements in it. My objective is to create a feature collection with a column per list and a row per element (2x4 table). But, I'm getting a feature collection with 3 columns and only 1 row (feature 0).

How do I get four different features instead of one?

My code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/ab24d70e19e02bf96a908ad9f3815f5e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to map accros the list. Instead of concatenating the lists i made a list of lists and then mapped a function.

```
var index = ee.List([['20190101T160509_20190101T160509_T17RNJ','17RNJ'],
                    ['20190104T160649_20190104T161509_T17RLH','17RLH'],
                    ['20190104T160649_20190104T161509_T17RMJ','17RMJ'],
                    ['20190104T160649_20190104T161509_T17RMK', '17RMK']]);

var featList = index.map(function(list){
  return ee.Feature(null).set({index:ee.List(list).get(0), id_tile:ee.List(list).get(1)})
})

var features = ee.FeatureCollection(featList)
print(features)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're doing things once that you need to do each feature. Your `features` variable is misnamed because it is actually only **one** feature.

You have:

```
var id_tile = ee.List(['17RNJ','17RLH','17RMJ','17RMK']);
var features = ee.Feature(null)
            .set('Index', index,'Tile ID', id_tile);
var table = ee.FeatureCollection([features]);
```

You should instead use:

```
// Put the "index" and the "id" into one list of pairs.
var indexes_and_ids = index.zip(id_tile);

// Construct one feature per pair.
var table = ee.FeatureCollection(indexes_and_ids.map(function (index_and_id) {
  var one_index = ee.List(index_and_id).get(0);
  var one_id = ee.List(index_and_id).get(1);
  return ee.Feature(null).set('Index', one_index,'Tile ID', one_id);
}));
```

Note, however, that it is much more convenient if you can avoid constructing parallel lists (lists of the same length that have corresponding elements). For example, since the elements in your `index` all have the same prefix, you could instead write:

```
var table = ee.FeatureCollection(id_tile.map(function (id) {
  return ee.Feature(null).set(
      'Index', ee.String('20190101T160509_20190101T160509_T').cat(id),
      'Tile ID', id);
}));
```

Of course, your actual situation rather than test data might be different than that. But this is even more important if your input is, say, an actual `ImageCollection` which you got those IDs from. In order to get efficient processing of large datasets, you need to use `ImageCollection`s and `FeatureCollections` without converting them to `List`s. You can usually do this with a `map` operation — for example you can map over an `ImageCollection`, reduce or otherwise process each image in it, and return a `Feature`, and the result will be a `FeatureCollection` that you can export.